# Использование мостов с torctl

Tags: tor

Сеть tor заблокирована в моей стране, поэтому мне нужно использовать мосты. Я запросил мосты в bridge-db и могу использовать их в браузере tor. Но как мне использовать мосты в torctl? Мой конфигурационный файл /etc/tor/torrc сейчас выглядит следующим образом:

```
Bridge obfs4 <ip:port> <fingerprint> cert=<cert> iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 <ip:port> <fingerprint> cert=<cert> iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 <ip:port> <fingerprint> cert=<cert> iat-mode=0
UseBridges 1
```

Но torctl все равно не использует мосты.